# Read-write pipe() communication in R

Tags: r, ipc, pipe

Most languages support two-way process communication.  For example, in Python, I can (sloppily) do:

```
>>> from subprocess import *
>>> p = Popen('nslookup', stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
>>> p_stdin, p_stdout = p.communicate("www.google.com")
>>> print p_stdin
Server:     ...
```

In R, I can only seem to go one way, regardless of whether I open my pipe with "r+" or "w+".   Furthermore, even if I run a script via `R -f ...` or `R < ...`, weird behavior ensues in the actual console stdin/stdout.

My question boils down to the following - is it possible (without writing a C method!) to reproduce the two-way process communication in the above Python example in R?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A long time ago I also used two-way pipes in [Octave](http://www.octave.org) so, yes, this would be nice to have.  But a perusal of `help(pipe)` does not suggest that this is support.  You get read *or* write, but seemingly not both.

But maybe you can cheat.  Open a pipe to write into an app which you can call with a stdout redirection to a file ... and then keep reading that file.  Could be a mess due to non-flushed buffers though.

Comment: Is this a platform compatibility issue with base?  Should I file a bug/issue there?

Also, the file option is technically a solution, but this is actually for piping large amounts of SQL results to avoid a buggy ODBC driver, so writing to disk and reading back in would be pretty slow.

Comment: I tried on Linux which would have it if R supported it.  No point in filing a bug report unless you can code it, or pay someone to do it -- R Core has hands full.  Lastly, personally I tend to avoid buggy ODBC drivers by ... writing direct DB access pieces.  Been there, done for backends such as Bloomberg, Lim, OneTick as well as PostgreSQL via some GSoC mentoring.  What is your backend?

Comment: @mjbommar, I also haven't found a way to do what you describe, and I spent a few hours trying. However, if you're just trying to get results from a SQL DB into R without using a ODBC driver, you probably don't need two way interactive. Try using system() to connect to it and feed your query as an input. I do this to access all of my databases (which require SSH tunneling that RMySQL can't do).

Comment: the DB on the other side is Vertica (and sadly the pgsql client doesn't work).  It sounds like I'll keep using the solution I have now, which is calling the SQL client with paste('echo', query, '|') in front, but that Dirk's answer is probably the right solution for most people.  I'll give it another few hours and then accept it.

Answer (score 13):

One way to do it on UNIX-like systems would be to open a pipe to a process that is redirecting `stdout` and `stderr` to a fifo:

```
# Setup
system('mkfifo output.fifo')
p_out <- fifo('output.fifo', 'r')
p_in <- pipe('pdflatex &> output.fifo', 'w')

# See what TeX said on startup
readLines(p_out)
[1] "This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.11 (TeX Live 2010)"

readLines(p_out)
character(0) # TeX has nothing more to say

# Tell TeX to do something
writeLines('\\documentclass{article}', p_in)
flush(p_in)

# See what it said in response
readLines(p_out)
[1] "**entering extended mode"                                                       
[2] "LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>"                                                           
[3] "Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ba"
[4] "sque, danish, dutch, finnish, french, german, ngerman, swissgerman, hungarian, "
[5] "italian, bokmal, nynorsk, polish, portuguese, spanish, swedish, loaded."        
[6] ""
```

Unfortunately, `fifo` isn't supported on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Its possible to run that part in Jython from R like this.  Loading java (which occurs in the second statement) will be slow but after that it should be ok.

```
library(rJython)

.Jython <- rJython()

jython.assign(.Jython, "x", "www.google.com")
jython.exec(.Jython, "from subprocess import *
p = Popen('nslookup', stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
p_stdin, p_stdout = p.communicate(x)")

cat(jython.get(.Jython, "p_stdin"), "\n\n")
```

The last statement gives:

```
> cat(jython.get(.Jython, "p_stdin"), "\n\n")
Default Server:  UnKnown

Address:  192.168.0.1



> www.google.com
```

Comment: I voted this up because it might work for some, but this option invokes too much overhead for my application.

Comment: @mbommar, Precisely what overhead are you referring to?  If its the speed then the only slow part is the `.Jython <- rJython()` statement (as that loads the JVM) and that only needs to be done once at the beginning of your session so it only affects startup time.  If startup time is of concern then I agree it would be a problem.