# Bidirectional communication between R and Python

Tags: python, r, ipc

I have some Python code that internally uses callbacks. I want to be able to call this code from within R and have the callbacks communicate with the R session (e.g. execute R code in the callbacks). Basically the Python code acts as a driver for R when called. I am not sure how to do this properly.

Packages like RPy and rPython don't seem to offer what I need. The Python code needs to maintain a specific state while doing the callbacks, so successive calls to Python functions from within R are ruled out.

As far as I can tell, the only solution involves launching a Python subprocess within R and then having them communicate when necessary. The communication would involve sequences like this:

- `Python -> R`: callback command
- `R -> Python`: the result of the callback

Having looked at a bunch of alternatives, I'm having a hard time coming up with the best communication strategy (bidirectional & platform-independent, ideally):

1. Use an anonymous pipe. This seems like the best solution to me, though [R only seems to support pipes that read *or* write (not both)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355280/read-write-pipe-communication-in-r).
2. Use a named pipe which can be closed and reopened to get both read and write functionality. The R session would be responsible for making and removing the named pipe before calling Python and after Python is finished, respectively.

I feel like I am overcomplicating things, but I can't think of alternatives. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not to use `rpy2` for example? You execute your R code in in `r objects`.

Comment: @agstudy if I am not mistaken, `rpy2` runs an *embedded R process*. In my use case I want to access data in an existing R workspace in the R callbacks (e.g. not create a new R workspace embedded inside Python). Can this be done using `rpy2`?

Answer (score 0):

the answer is old, but if someone need a tool without installation check out this:
https://github.com/jstar88/pyCommunicator

It's able to communicate and use callback as you asked