# Capture and process output from external commands from R

Tags: r, io, stdout

Take this simple python script for example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# /tmp/xxx.py

import time

for i in range(1000):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(1)
```

It continuously outputs numbers. I can call it from R like this:

```
system2("/tmp/xxx.py", stdin=?)
```

where stdin can be set to NULL, "", TRUE or a filename. But what I am looking for is a way to process these numbers in realtime. For example, whenever a number is printed from this python script, I want to multiply the number by Pi and then print it to the console. Is there a way to do this in R?

Comment: Any feedback on my answer would be appreciated. You know how SO works... I had spent close to an hour on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an expert, but I got something working.

First of all, I used the following `/tmp/xxx.R` executable Rscript instead of your python script as I found out python was buffering its output (not printing one line at a time) which makes it hard to test:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

for (i in 1:5) {
   cat(i, "\n")
   Sys.sleep(1)
}
```

Then the R code:

```
system('mkfifo /tmp/xxx.fifo')
f <- fifo("/tmp/xxx.fifo", 'r')
p <- pipe('/tmp/xxx.R > /tmp/xxx.fifo; echo OVER > /tmp/xxx.fifo', 'w')

while(TRUE) {
   line <- readLines(f, n = 1)
   if (length(line) > 0) {
      if (line == "OVER") break
      cat(pi * as.numeric(line), "\n")
   }
   Sys.sleep(0.1)
}
close(f)
close(p)
```

some of which was inspired from this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5561188/1201032.

Hope it answers your question.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response, I came up with this question in a random thought and then forgot about it, you know, these things happen. This works very well on Linux and osx. Probably will not work on windows?